# Showing $[\hat{A},\hat{B}] = i\mathbb{1} \Leftrightarrow [\hat{A},\hat{B}^{\textstyle n}] = i\,n\,B^{\textstyle n-1}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

Actually it is self redundant to show having in mind $[\hat{A},\hat{B}^{\textstyle n}] = \,n\,B^{\textstyle n-1}\,[\hat{A},\hat{B}]$ but I suppose it is not supposed to solve it this way. Instead I guess the primal relation $[\hat{A},\hat{B}] = i\mathbb{1}$ has to be exploited. Expanding is not getting me further:

$(1) \quad[\hat{A},\hat{B}] = \hat{A}\,\hat{B}-\hat{B}\,\hat{A} = i\,\mathbb{1}$

$(2)\quad[\hat{A},\hat{B}^{\textstyle n}] = \hat{A}\,\hat{B}^{\textstyle n}- \hat{B}^{\textstyle n}\,\hat{A} = i\,n\,B^{\textstyle n-1}$

Briefly how the one follows from the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite straightforwards operator manipulation.

$we \ have: \ [\hat{A}, \hat{B}]= \hat{A}\hat{B}-\hat{B}\hat{A}=i \mathbb{I} \implies \hat{B}\hat{A}=\hat{A}\hat{B}-i\mathbb{I}$

$THUS:$

$$[A,B^n] = AB^n - B^n A = AB^{n}-B^{n-1}(BA) \\
=AB^{n} -B^{n-1} (AB - i1)\\ 
=AB^{n} -B^{n-2}(BA)B + iB^{n-1}  \\
=AB^{n} - B^{n-2}(AB-i1)B+iB^{n-1} \\
=AB^{n-} - B^{n-2}(AB-i1)B+iB^{n-1}  \\
=AB^{n}-B^{n-2}AB^2+iB^{n-1}+iB^{n-1} \\
=AB^{n}-B^{n-2}AB^2+2iB^{n-1} \\
. . . \\
...\\
...\\
=AB^n - BAB^{n-1} +i(n-1)B^{n-1}  \\
=AB^n - AB^{n} +iB^{n-1}+i(n-1)B^{n-1} \\ 
=inB^{n-1}
$$
hence proved. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $-\hat{B}^n \hat{A} = -\hat{B}^{n-1}\hat{B}\hat{A} = \hat{B}^{n-1}(i\mathbb{1}-\hat{A}\hat{B})$ and then you can continue with
$-\hat{B}^{n-1}\hat{A}\hat{B}=-\hat{B}^{n-2}\hat{B}\hat{A}\hat{B}=\hat{B}^{n-2}(i\mathbb{1}-\hat{A}\hat{B})\hat{B}$.
Can you see the pattern?